# CRM 2011 Pre-Operation plug-in offline - changes not being synchronized to the server, while displayed offline

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am getting strange behavior in Synchronization in Dynamics CRM Outlook Client with Offline access. We have a plug-in that runs Offline in pre-operation stage when a Contact is created, setting a calculated field's value.

targetEntity.Attributes[fieldName] = newValue;

After the Contact is created the field is set and everything is working correctly while Offline, but after synchronization the field is being blanked. I checked OfflineQueue table on the client and I can see that the SOAP message does not contain information on the modified field, so this would be the reason why the information is not being brought to the server. **It seems like the SOAP message is inserted into OfflineQueue table BEFORE the pre-operation stage and is not modified do to changes in plug-in.** Has anyone seen this before? Is this a bug in CRM - I cannot find any information on this?

Answer (score 0):

did you try it on post-operation?
register plugin step on post-operation, than retrieve the created contact and update field.
targetEntity.Attributes[fieldName] = newValue;
hope it will work